# F2PY: Passing single-element arrays to Fortran

Tags: f2py

The following Fortran code fills a 2D array x with value v

```
      subroutine fill(x,v,m,n)
      real*8 x(m,n),v
      integer m,n,i
cf2py intent(in) :: x,v,m,n
      forall(i=1:m,j=1:n) x(i,j) = v
      end
```

When calling this function from Python:

```
x = numpy.array([[[0.0]]],order='F')
fill(x[:,:,0],2.0)
assert(x[0,0,0]==2.0) # Assertion failed
```

Why is this assertion failing ?

Comment: Um...`copy(x,y)` do you mean `copy(x,y,1)`?

Answer (score 3):

x should be declared as `intent(inout)` if you want it to pass values back to the caller.

However this causes an additional problem because passing array slices doesn't work for `intent(inout)` arrays.  In this simple example you can get around it by calling from python:

`fill(x, 2.0)`.

If you really wanted to pass a slice then you need to declare x as intent(in,out), and call from python:
`x[:,:,0] = fill(x[:,:,0],2.0)`

The description of the different attributes can be found at:

http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e/usersguide/index.html#attributes

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. Neither `intent(inout)` nor `intent(inplace)` fixed it. The problem is obviously in the array checking routine `array_from_pyobj()` in `fortranobject.c`, which ships with `f2py` and is linked with every module one builds. `array_from_pyobj()` makes every effort that any input is converted to a properly shaped contiguous array, doing many many checks. One of them does not work properly with single-element arrays, such that a copy is made instead of working on the original array.

One could fix that, but ...well... I don't want any of this polymorphism stuff in an interface to a performance library anyway... I have a Python class wrapping the library calls that already guarantees that all the arguments are passed on correctly.

So my fix was to make my own copy of `fortranobject.c` and simply replace `array_from_pyobj()` by the following dummy version:

```
extern PyArrayObject * 
array_from_pyobj(const int type_num, npy_intp *dims,
                 const int rank, const int intent, PyObject *obj) {

    int i;
    PyArrayObject *arr = (PyArrayObject *)obj;

    for (i=0; i<arr->nd; ++i)
        dims[i] = arr->dimensions[i];
    return arr;
}
```

My plan is to use the original `fortranobject.c` during development of my Python wrapper class, where admittedly it is an advantage to get gentle error messages instead of hard crashes every time one makes a mistake calling a library function. Once I'm sure that all the library calls work, I'll use my custom `fortranobject.c`, which also works with single-element arrays.